# PagerSlidingTabStrip: ViewPager tabs alignment to right

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, arabic, pagerslidingtabstrip

How to align the tabs in the ViewPager to the right instead of the left? I am using `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` if that matters.

[image]

I've tried `android:layout_gravity="right"` but it doesn't affect the alignment:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: Your `layout_gravity` is on the `ViewPager`, not the tabs.

Comment: @CommonsWare OK cool, how to access the tabs?

Comment: You must know the answer to that, because you are the one who put the tabs there, whether with a `PagerTabStrip`, the `TabPagerIndicator` from the ViewPagerIndicator library, or something else. `ViewPager` does not have tabs on its own.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ah I see. I am using `PagerSlidingTabStrip` BTW.

Comment: Right. Try adjusting its `gravity` or `layout_gravity`. For something like a tab strip, I could see either of those being the right answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @CommonsWare for his help. I just needed to change this line:

```
tabsContainer = new LinearLayout(context);
```

to

```
tabsContainer = new LinearLayout(context);
tabsContainer.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

Comment: no need for this, just use psts:pstsShouldExpand="true"

Answer (score 4):

Or you just add this line:`app:pstsShouldExpand="true"`

to be:

```
<com.example.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    app:pstsShouldExpand="true" />
```

Comment: thanks it's works fine !! In case you are using Custom view on the tab then we should also include  *android:gravity="center"* for the custom view

Answer (score 1):

You should be setting it to

```
 <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
...
android:layout_gravity="right"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
tabsContainer.setLayoutDirection(LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
tabsContainer.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```